# tensorflow_datasets module not found Mac OS VScode Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, debugging, visual-studio-code, tensorflow-datasets

I have downloaded tensorflow and tensorflow_datasets (pip3 install tensorflow_datasets for the latter) and they both show up in my pip3 list when I run it in the terminal. When I try to run code after doing `import tensorflow_datasets as tfds` I get an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_datasets'` . I don't believe I need to use conda or jupyter or anything else like some of the other stackoverflow answers suggest, so I am not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you have installed the packages into the environment which you are using. Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import sys
sys.append("path")
```

The `path` should be the same path, where you installed tensorflow_datasets.